# NumberFormatException when parsing negative integer

Tags: java, palindrome, parseint

I am writing a java program to determine if a number is a palindrome.

My code works properly if the argument passed is a positive integer, but throws a NumberFormatException when passing a negative integer.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at com.stu.Main.isPalindrome(Main.java:28)
at com.stu.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

The following solution I took from another stackoverflow thread, which seems to be what the instructor wants us to use, however in the while loop I assume that since a negative number is always less than 0, it will break out of the loop and not calculate the palindrome:

```
public static int reverse(int number)
        {  
            int result = 0;
            int remainder;
            while (number > 0)
            {
                remainder = number % 10;
                number = number / 10;
                result = result * 10 + remainder;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

So, I am using strings in my solution below to solve this issue.

Note: we have not yet got to splits and regexps yet.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        isPalindrome(-1221); // throws exception
        isPalindrome(707);   // works as expected - returns true
        isPalindrome(11212); // works as expected - returns false
        isPalindrome(123321);// works as expected - returns true
    }


    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number){

        if(number < 10 && number > -10) {
            return false;
        }

        String origNumber = String.valueOf(number);
        String reverse = "";

        while(number > 0) {
            reverse += String.valueOf(number % 10);
            number /= 10;
        }

        if(Integer.parseInt(origNumber) == Integer.parseInt(reverse)) {
            System.out.println("The original number was " + origNumber + "     and the reverse is " + reverse);
            System.out.println("Number is a palindrome!");
            return true;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("The original number was " + origNumber + " and the reverse is " + reverse);
            System.out.println("Sorry, the number is NOT a palindrome!");
            return false;
    }
}
```

I am looking for two things here.

First, how do I solve the issue with the negative number in the while loop in the case of the instructors preferred solution?

Second, how can I solve the NumberFormatException in my solution?

Edit: a third question. Why does my solution return false if I never parse back to an int?

```
if(Integer.parseInt(origNumber) == Integer.parseInt(reverse)) // works
```

to

```
if(origNumber == reverse) // does not work
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the text of the number format exception which you're getting. Include the stacktrace and indicate which line of your code is throwing the exception.

Comment: If you read the exception message carefully, you are attempting to parse  an empty string.

Comment: I understand the exception, and saw that posted in another thread, however I am not sure how to solve the issue

Comment: And just a quick hint: when you already turned 123 into "123", you don't need any math any more to get to "321". A string consists of chars, and as you already **have** a string, just reverse the chars in there. The math is nice, but not needed at all, when you already decided to work with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the easiest way to solve your first and second problem is just to remove the negative sign by using `Math.abs(yourNumber)` and that's it. 
As,

```
The java.lang.Math.abs() returns the absolute value of a given argument.

If the argument is not negative, the argument is returned.
If the argument is negative, the negation of the argument is returned.
```

This will solve both of your first and second problem.

Coming to the third one, if you are not converting back to integer you are getting false as to compare string you neet to use `equals()` method as,

```
== tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
.equals() tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").
```

Hope that helps!! ;)

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps, especially the third issue comparing string values! However, even though I know how to manipulate strings and use the Math functions (I have studied Java before, although its been a while), I am trying to solve the problem without it as we haven't yet reached that part in the course. Also, if I use the absolute value function I am not able to correctly display the original negative number in my output

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if that answers your question.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not to accept this as a solution. It will work, however it doesn't exactly answer my original question as it uses the absolute value function which I am trying to avoid (haven't got there in the course yet).

Comment: Simply store the original number in a different variable before using Math function and then use that variable in the end to print the initial number.

Comment: Adding one more thing to the NumberFormatException, when you reverse a negative number using the string rules you will get something like '453-' if the number is '-354' and when you parse the reverse you will get the exception for sure.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as just outputting the number variable twice - which would not actually be outputting the found palindrome? Ex: System.out.println("The original number was " + origNumber + " and the reverse is " + origNumber);

Comment: If I understand correctly, the exception is coming from the formatting of the negative number which will not parse correctly (-354 is fine, but 453- is not a proper integer)?

Comment: Not exactly, what I meant was to save the reverse in a new variable after converting it into positive and then process that which will keep your original number intact.

Comment: Yes 453- is not a proper integer as it doesn't follow the math rule of representation of numbers

Comment: Awarding you the solution as you answered my questions and provided sufficient help! Thanks again! For the professors solution, simply changing the while (number > 0) to while (number != 0) will fix the issue with using negatives.